Dilithium Crystals: Warp space directly or just supply the energy to do so?
I am extremely behind the current series as well as the Star Trek books but surely someplace just how the crystals work. My sense is that they have something to do with antimatter and perhaps then are concerned with generating the necessary energy to warp space but are not directly concerned with the warping itself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilithium_(Star_Trek)

You are correct. Per Memory Alpha, dilithium crystals control the flow of matter and antimatter, allowing energy to be drawn into the warp engines for space travel.

In Starfleet starships, dilithium was used to regulate the
matter/antimatter reaction. Injectors would feed matter and antimatter
into the dilithium chamber, where the two substances would mix and
react, with the dilithium crystals used to control the reaction. (ENT:
"Bound")

Dilithium is canonically not required for warp itself - Zefram Cochrane's space craft, the first human vessel to warp space, did not have dilithium.

It's not as called out in the Tech manual as I used to think - it's implied by the episode Pen Pals in my opinion that Dilithium down converts gamma rays from the M-AntiM reaction into heat energy that the warp plasma needs to do its magic.  I also used to think the warp plasma would be recycled to be reheated but honestly the Tech manual implies it is destroyed/sent into subspace - so I gave up on this type of trek physics question. I'm pretty sure there some reference on how dilithium can be made embedded in subspace that the anti-m doesn't react with it but only the matter stream.

I think it's in the the novel "Federation" by Judith and Garfield Reeve-Stevens where the periodic table is stated to be actually three dimensional. Dilithium and lithium share the same x y coordinate, but dilithium has a higher z coordinate.  Some percentage of all Earth lithium is discovered to actually be dilithium.   The "lithium cracking station" that Kirk visits in TOS is separating lithium from dilithium (Star Fleet Technical Manual, I think).

According to an episode of TNG, the romulans didn't use matter/antimatter reactions as power for warp travel either- they used singularities- basically miniature, artificially created black holes.
